# Rename txt-files using part of first textline in file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have a need of a code used in a batch file that renames bankfiles created from SAP (I am a SAP-man), stored in a location on the server.

**Problem:** All bank-files get a name from a sequence table in SAP (date + number).  Before I send them to the bank they have to have a certain name structure.

I have a code and this has worked fine up to now.  The problem now is that i send a "batch" (several) of files from SAP and they are named randomly.
In the first line of each file there is a unique batch ID, that is a bank sequence number and the files has to be named in this order.
I have done a lot of VBA programming, but i am not to strong in this subject.

**Needed solution:** What i need is that for each file it should read the first line of the file and fetch position 71 and 4 positions forward, save this in a variable and add it to the end of the file name.

**Example:** If the original file name from SAP is 20160301-001.txt I want to rename it to "P.00934681758.005.TBII.00000xxxx.txt" (where "xxxx" is the position 71 to 74 in the first line of the file.

It looks through a lot of bank directories today, but below you can find todays code (that work, except that in this code it renumbers "a", starting with no 1 - never more than 9 files) and i want to replace it with these 4 digits from the file:

**Todays name:** P.00934681758.005.TBII.00000!a!.dat ("a" beeing a variable)

**New name:** P.00934681758.005.TBII.00xxxx.dat ("xxxx" the digits from the file)

**Todays code** (part of it - showing 2 "scanned" directories)**:**

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

REM Start by renaming all files in each folder to the namerule of the bank

cd PL270\UT01

set a=1

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *') do (
    if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0" (
        ren "%%i" "P.00934681758.002.TBII.00000!a!".dat 
        set /a a+=1
 )
) 

cd..
cd..\PL570\UT01

set a=1

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *') do (
    if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0" (
        ren "%%i" "P.00934681758.005.TBII.00000!a!".dat 
        set /a a+=1
 )
)
```

The code is run in a *.bat-file today, scheduled every 5th minute on the server.

All help will be VERY much appreciated:-)

B.r. Solve

Comment: so you `a` should be the ID from the first line of each file?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question you need to replace hardcoded a with a code readed from the file you'are renaming:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *') do (
    set /p fline=<"%%i"
    set code=!fline:~70,4!
    echo !code!
    if not "%%~nxi"=="%~nx0" (
        ren "%%i" "P.00934681758.002.TBII.00000!code!".dat 
        set /a a+=1
 )
)
```

(once I've worked for SAP - most boring I ever had...)

Comment: Thank you very much npocmaka:-)  This worked beutifully.  Simple and funtional.

Comment: By the way, I am also a financial guy - that might explain why i like working with SAP (i know some consider it to be boring:).  I am having my own company together with my daughter and we have been overbooked for 10 years - not many can say that:-)

Answer (score 0):

The following script walks through a given directory tree and searches for matching files. A file is considered matching if its name begins with today's date in the format `YYYYMMDD`, followed by a `-`, followed by a number, followed by extension`.txt`. For each file found, the demanded characters are extracted from the first line, then they are appended to the prefix `P.00934681758.005.TBII.00`, and the extension `.dat` is appended.

The behaviour of the batch file can be controlled by the constants defined at the beginning. To learn how it works and what happens, consult the `rem` comments throughout the whole file.

Here is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Definition of constants:
set "LOCATION=%~dp0" & rem Working directory; `%~dp0` is container, `.` is current;
set "RECURSIVE=#" & rem Flag to walk through working directory recursively, if defined;
set "SEPARATOR=-" & rem Separator character of original file name (one character!);
set "PATTERN=????????%SEPARATOR%*.txt" & rem Search pattern for `dir`;
rem Filter for `findstr /R` to match only correct file names (`.*` deactivates it):
set "REGEX=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%SEPARATOR%[0-9][0-9]*\.txt";
rem Filter for date prefix in file names (fixed date like `YYYYMMDD`, all files if empty):
set "TODAY=%DATE:~,4%%DATE:~5,2%%DATE:~8,2%" & rem Expected `%DATE%` format: `YYYY/MM/DD`;
set "NEWNAME=P.00934681758.005.TBII.00" & rem Beginning of new file name;
set "NEWEXT=.dat" & rem New file extension;
set "NUMLINE=0" & rem Zero-based line number where to extract characters from;
set "POSITION=70,4" & rem Zero-based start position, number of characters (length);
set "FORCE=#" & rem Flag to force extracted characters not to be empty, if defined;

rem Change to working directory:
pushd "%LOCATION%" || (
    >&2 echo Cannot find "%LOCATION%". & exit /B 1
)
rem Initialise some variables:
set /A NUMLINE+=0
if %NUMLINE% LEQ 0 (set "NUMSKIP=") else (set "NUMSKIP=skip^=%NUMLINE%^ ")
if defined RECURSIVE (set "RECURSIVE=/S ")
rem Walk through directory (tree) and search for matching file names (sorted by name):
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B %RECURSIVE%/A:-D /O:-N-D "%PATTERN%" ^| ^
        findstr /R /C:"^%REGEX%$" /C:"\\%REGEX%$"
') do (
    rem Split file name by given separator:
    for /F "eol=| tokens=1,* delims=%SEPARATOR%" %%I in ("%%~nxF") do (
        set "PREFIX=%%I"
        set "SUFFIX=%%J"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem Check whether first part of file name matches today's date:
        if "%TODAY%"=="" (set "TODAY=!PREFIX!")
        if "!PREFIX!"=="!TODAY!" (
            set "OLDNAME=!PREFIX!%SEPARATOR%!SUFFIX!"
            rem Extract characters from predefined position from file (sub-routine):
            call :EXTRACT PORTION "!OLDNAME!"
            if defined FORCE (
                rem Check extracted character string if empty optionally:
                if not defined PORTION (
                    >&2 echo Nothing at position ^(%POSITION%^). & popd & exit /B 1
                )
            )
            rem Build new file name using extracted character string:
            set "BUILTNAME=%NEWNAME%!PORTION!%NEWEXT%"
            rem Check whether a file with the new name already exists:
            if not exist "!BUILTNAME!" (
                rem Actually rename file here (as soon as `ECHO` is removed!):
                ECHO ren "!OLDNAME!" "!BUILTNAME!"
            ) else (
                >&2 echo "!BUILTNAME!" already exists. & popd & exit /B 1
            )
        ) else (
            endlocal
            rem First part of file name does not match today's date, so leave loop:
            goto :CONTINUE
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
:CONTINUE
popd

endlocal
exit /B

:EXTRACT PORTION "FileSpec"
rem Sub-routine to extract characters from a file at a given position;
set "PART="
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Read specified line from given file:
for /F usebackq^ %NUMSKIP%delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%~2") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    if defined LINE (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem Extract specified sub-string of read line by position and length:
        set "PART=!LINE:~%POSITION%!"
        if  defined PART (
            for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%S in ("!PART!") do (
                endlocal
                set "PART=%%S"
            )
        ) else (
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem Do not read any more lines from the file, leave loop:
    goto :QUIT
)
:QUIT
rem Return extracted character string:
endlocal & set "%~1=%PART%"
exit /B
```

The script does no renaming as long as you do not **remove the upper-case `ECHO`** in front of the `ren` command.